# Can't use .NET methods in deployed matlab dll

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, dll, matlab-deployment

Using [Matlab Compiler SDK](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/?s_tid=srchtitle) I can deploy my Matlab code into a dll that can be loaded in a C# application. 
Now I would also add a .NET reference into my Matlab code using the [NET.addAssembly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/net.addassembly.html?s_tid=srchtitle) matlab command. If I run my code in Matlab I can access the method of the class that I've imported. Unfortunately, if I compile my Matlab code (with the added .net reference) to have my usual dll it seems that the methods of the .net class that I have imported in my matlab code cannot be seen anymore (matlab throws an error "No appropriate method, property, or field 'MyMethodName' for class 'MyNameSpace.MyClass'".
Is there someone that can help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

PS: It could seem weird to have a .NET project that reference a Matlab compiled dll that reference another c# dll. The reason is that I need to convert all my (big) Matlab project in a c# and I would like to do it by step by step but without affecting the main (C#) aplication.

Comment: I'm performing same kind operation (calling homemade .net assemblies from matlab code and then compile this last one) without issues. Are you sure you added all assembly files to compilation process (`-a` in matlab compiler options) and that these are the last compiled ones ? Very likely that if you can instantiate the object and the method is not found is that it's not last compiled assembly which is tied to compiled matlab code.

Comment: @CitizenInsane As far I understood from Matlab documentation, -a option is required only for those files that cannot be located automatically by the Dependency Analysis Function (`depfun`). In particular all dependencies of MEX-files, DLLs, or shared libraries must be added using -a option. However, my dll does not have any dependency, so I don't need to add any -a option. Since `NET.AddAssembly` needs the absolute path to the dll I just need to have the dll in the same location also on production PC. In fact the cause of the error was different (see my solution).

Comment: @CitizenInsane Are you also able to attach to the the process of the main application in order to debug your "home made" .net assemblies?

Comment: I've never tried ... I debug/test .net code separately from matlab one.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact there is a class with the same name and same namespace in the main application (i.e. MyNameSpace.MyClass). This seems to hide the class that is defined on the assembly that I load from Matlab.

I changed the name of the Namespace of the class that I load in Matlab and now it works.